# Is it possible to use Hibernate for OLAP-server?

Tags: olap, hibernate

I have a PostgreSQL database with Java Hibernate. I need a XMLA datasource for a pivot grid client component.

- Is it possible to use Hibernate for a OLAP-server?
- Which OLAP-server does support Hibernate (POJOs)?